# Slack/Botkit: How to make bot in slack listen better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, slack, botkit

I'm having issues with creating a way where the bot correctly listens within a slack channel without replying to everything being said in the channel.

So, here is the way I currently approached this:

```
controller.hears(['You\'re awesome','Help',"What would Jeremy say?", "Hello","Top 5", "Hi", "I love you", /^.{0,}jirabot.{0,}$/], ['direct_message','direct_mention','mention','ambient'],function(bot,message) {

   console.log(message);

 // This will show the last 5 created tickets in Zendesk
   if(message.text === "Top 5"){
     try{
         Do this thing
     });
   }catch(err){
     bot.reply(message, 'I\'m sorry I did not get that. Please try again.');
   }

 }

   else if (message.text === "You're Awesome"){
       bot.reply(message, 'Nah, You\'re Awesome <@'+message.user+'>');
     }
   else {
        bot.reply(message, 'I\'m sorry I don\'t understand');
        }
```

This way works, but it if someone says something else it keeps saying I'm sorry I don't understand. How do I make the bot not say that every time?

I also tried this way, but the bot terminates and won't do anything else after one of the actions is completed:

```
  var hi = 'HI';
    var love = 'I LOVE YOU';

controller.hears([hi, /^.{0,}jirabot.{0,}$/],['direct_message','direct_mention','mention','ambient'],function(bot,message) {

  // start a conversation to handle this response.
  bot.startConversation(message,function(err,convo) {

      if (message.text.toLowerCase() === hi.toLowerCase()){
        bot.reply(message, 'What can I do for you? <@'+message.user+'>');
      convo.next();
    }else{
      bot.reply(message, 'Sorry, I don\'t understand');
      convo.next();
    }

  });
});
controller.hears([love, /^.{0,}jirabot.{0,}$/],['direct_message','direct_mention','mention','ambient'],function(bot,message) {

  // start a conversation to handle this response.
  bot.startConversation(message,function(err,convo) {

      if (message.text.toLowerCase() === love.toLowerCase()){
        bot.reply(message, 'No, I love you more <@'+message.user+'>');
      convo.next();
    }else{
      bot.reply(message, 'Sorry, I don\'t understand');
      convo.next();
    }

  });
});
```

Any ideas or feedback would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are matching any occurrence of those strings anywhere in user input. So you would trigger this user input: `hi` but also this input: `hildjf` or `I love shiitake mushrooms!`

I ran your code as is and it wasn't triggering on all user input to the channel, only the strings listed in hears.

Use some regex to lock down the matches, use `^` to denote the beginning of a string and `$` for the end. So to match a user saying just the string `hi`, use the pattern `'^hi$'`. You won't match partial strings anymore, like `shiitake`